# C# server and Java client TCP

Tags: java, c#, tcp

The problem is `GetBufferSize` method, I send a buffer size of 40 and it returns some weird number 54124.
Why is this dose the java int byte code different from C# int byte code?

**JAVA CLIENT**

```java
mBufferOut = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), UTF8)), true);

private void sendMessage(final String message) {

    if (mBufferOut != null && message != null) {
        try {
            Log.d("_TAG", "Message length: " + Integer.toString(message.length()));

            Log.d("_TAG", "Sending: " + message);
            mBufferOut.print(message.length());
            mBufferOut.flush();
            mBufferOut.print(message);
            mBufferOut.flush();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The code above sends two messages: the first one is the buffer size and the second is the data itself.

**C# SERVER**

```
private void Read() {
    int size = GetBufferSize();

    byte[] myReadBuffer = new byte[size];
    int numberOfBytesRead = 0;
    string str = "";

    do
    {
        numberOfBytesRead = networkStream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);

        str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(myReadBuffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead);
    } while (networkStream.DataAvailable);
}

private int GetBufferSize()
{
    byte[] myReadBuffer = new byte[4];
    int numberOfBytesRead = 0;

    do
    {
        numberOfBytesRead = networkStream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
    } while (networkStream.DataAvailable);

    if (numberOfBytesRead > 0)
    {
        return BitConverter.ToInt32(myReadBuffer, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I recommend looking at the bytes you send and those you receive as individual bytes. Check that they are the same. Work out how they represent the human-readable value you are sending. Work out how they represent the erroneous value you're receiving.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

```
         `return   Int32.Parse(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length))`;
```

**Problem**

> public void print (int inum)
>
> Prints the string representation of the specified integer to the
> target.

The Integer get converted to the string representation  of that int then converted to bytes.

Comment: Surely the proper solution would be to send the value as bytes?

Comment: Ok but PrintWriter does not allow byte sending or is it , i checked it there is no methods available all of them take some other data type

Comment: I'm not familiar with Java, but: I think your problem stems from using text encoding to send your data. I imagine that the stream returned by `getOutputStream()` is capable of writing bytes. You're wrapping it with `OutputStreamWriter` which, according to the docs, is a bridge from character streams to byte streams. It depends how much work you want to put into it really. You could also just send "length,message" and then `GetBufferSize()` could just read until it hits the comma, and then parse the length out of the pre-comma string.

Comment: I'm also not familiar with Java, i searched out you can warp it with binaryformatter and write bytes directly.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you're having an issue regarding endianness. Java stores data in big endian, and .NET stores data based on your system architecture. If you're on a x86 machine, it's likely you're trying to read big-endian data as if it were little-endian. You'll have to reverse the byte array before reading it

```
            if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
            {
                Array.Reverse(buffer);
            }
```

[Here's more info in endianness.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

Comment: Actually both the Oracle JVM and Microsoft CLR store data in the same way, it’s system dependent. How they write that data to streams may differ.

Comment: 35 buffer size turned into 859111424 ,i added your code did not work

Comment: the android device is VM ,and Windows applications is x86

Comment: @vandench Data inside the JVM is stored depending on the system architecture. However any multibyte data item stored in a program running on the JVM are big-endian. [See page 69 of this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=LiCKAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA69&lpg=PA69&dq=does+jvm+store+data+big+endian&source=bl&ots=HdnZEpO0Dl&sig=rxJL7Ft4jcOVy7Za03pjrLi1eU4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj79cu9iM_dAhWHzlMKHU6qC60Q6AEwCXoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=does%20jvm%20store%20data%20big%20endian&f=false)